# Google Compute API: new instance with external IP

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to dynamically create Compute instances on Google Cloud via PHP using API.

Using [csmartinez Cloud API sample](https://github.com/csmartinez/Google-Cloud-Storage-API-Practice/blob/master/app.php), I managed to create my instance and can see it running on Google Console.

I need to assign an external IP address to this newly created instance. Based on the API and Google PHP library, I then added:

```
$ipName = "foo";
$addr = new Google_Service_Compute_Address();
$addr->setName($ipName);
$response = $service->addresses->insert($project, $ipZone, $addr);
```

Since this call has a "pending" status at first, I added a sleep(5) so I can then get the newly created static IP:

```
$response = $service->addresses->get($project, $ipZone, $ipName);
$ip = $response->address;
```

which runs well and gives me the correct IP address. I then continue and try to create my instance while assigning the new IP:

```
$networkConfig = new Google_Service_Compute_AccessConfig();
$networkConfig->setNatIP($ip);
$networkConfig->setType("ONE_TO_ONE_NAT");
$networkConfig->setName("External NAT");
$googleNetworkInterfaceObj->setAccessConfigs($networkConfig);
```

The static IP is created, the instance is created, but IP is not assigned to the instance.
To remove my doubt about the pending status, I also tried to assign an already created static IP to my instance, thus using:

```
$networkConfig->setNatIP("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

With no more success... What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line:

```
$googleNetworkInterfaceObj->setAccessConfigs($networkConfig);
```

should be:

```
$googleNetworkInterfaceObj->setAccessConfigs(array($networkConfig));
```

If this doesn't work, there might be another error somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks ! I missed the array() here, even thouth I used it on the other assignations.. Good spot :)

Comment: Did this answer solve your issue ? If the error was somewhere else, can you insert that as a new answer ?

Answer (score 0):

this would be the whole procedure, which assigns a network:

```
$instance = new Google_Instance();
$instance->setKind("compute#instance");

$accessConfig = new Google_AccessConfig();
$accessConfig->setName("External NAT");
$accessConfig->setType("ONE_TO_ONE_NAT");

$network = new Google_NetworkInterface();
$network->setNetwork($this->getObjectUrl($networkName, 'networks', $environment->getPlatformConfigValue(self::PROJECT_ID)));
$network->setAccessConfigs(array($accessConfig));

$instance->setNetworkInterfaces(array($network));
```

`$addr->setName()` is barely cosmetic; try `$addr->setAddress($ipAddress)`.

guess the `Google_NetworkInterface` would need the `$addr` assigned.

sorry, currently have no spare IP and do not want to pay only to provide code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have to use setName() as I provide a name for my static IP address, which value's assigned by Google when created. I'll test with your other parts tho, thanks