# How to programmatically set external ip for Google Cloud virtual machine in Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-compute-engine

I am trying to programmatically start Google Cloud virtual machine instances. It occurred to me that in order to have internet access, have to set an external IP address.

```
        // Access Config
        AccessConfig accessConfig = AccessConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setNatIP("foo")
                    .setType("ONE_TO_ONE_NAT")
                    .setName("External NAT")
                    .setExternalIpv6("bar")
                    .build();
        
        // Use the network interface provided in the networkName argument.
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.newBuilder()
                .setName(networkName)
                .setAccessConfigs(0, accessConfig)
                .build();
```

That is my status quo. It is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279420/google-compute-api-new-instance-with-external-ip) article post. I hoped that would work in Java, too, but currently, I am stuck.

All I get is:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: Bad Request
```

Unfortunately, Google Cloud Compute Engine Docs doesn't really provide any further information, on how to set the external IP properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the answer. In the Google Cloud Compute Engine Docs it is explained for [Windows Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/samples/compute-create-windows-instance-external-ip?hl=en). It took me a while to recognize it because I've focused only Linux Instances' related questions.

The solution:

```
instanceResource = Instance.newBuilder()
                .setName(instanceName)
                .setMachineType(machineType)
                .addDisks(disk)
                // Add external internet to instance
                .addNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.newBuilder()
                        .addAccessConfigs(AccessConfig.newBuilder()
                                .setType("ONE_TO_ONE_NAT")
                                .setName("External NAT")
                                .build())
                        .setName("global/networks/default")
                        .build())
                .setMetadata(buildMetadata())
                .build();
```